# Why shows the RecyclerView no header if the ArrayList is empty?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My `RecyclerView` displays `CardViews` and a Header.
The `Cardviews` get values from `json` and the Header gets values from given parameters in the activity before.

My problem is that the `Reyclerview` only displays the Header if `json` for the `CardView` is not empty, but if `json` sends no empty values to `CardView` the Header is shown.

**RecyclerViewAdapter**:

```
        public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

            Context context;

            private Activity activity;

            List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter;
            List<ExerciseAdapter> exerciseAdapter;
            private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;

            private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
            public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter, List<ExerciseAdapter> exerciseAdapter){

                super();

                this.exerciseAdapter = exerciseAdapter;
                this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
                this.context = context;
            }

            private GetDataAdapter getItem(int position)
            {
                return getDataAdapter.get(position);

            }


            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
                     View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
                     return new ViewHolder(itemView);
                }
                if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
                    //Inflating header view
                    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
                    return new HeaderViewHolder(itemView);
                }
                return null;
            }



            class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

                public TextView edit;
                public TextView NameTextView;
                public TextView PhoneNumberTextView;
                public TextView SubjectTextView;
                public NetworkImageView imageView1;
                public NetworkImageView imageView2;
                public NetworkImageView imageView3;
                public NetworkImageView imageView4;
                public NetworkImageView imageView5;
                public TextView ratebutton;


                public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

                    super(itemView);
                    edit = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
                    NameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4) ;
                    PhoneNumberTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView6) ;
                    SubjectTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView8) ;
                    imageView1 = (NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1t);
                    imageView2 = (NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2t);
                    imageView3 = (NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3t);
                    imageView4 = (NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4t);
                    imageView5 = (NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5t);
                    ratebutton = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratebutton);



                }
            }



            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                if (holder instanceof ViewHolder) {

                    if (position != 0) {
                      final GetDataAdapter current = getItem(position - 1);


                        final ViewHolder holder1 = (ViewHolder) holder;
                        final ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
                        final ImageLoader imageLoader2 = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
                        final ImageLoader imageLoader3 = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
                        final ImageLoader imageLoader4 = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
                        final ImageLoader imageLoader5 = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

                        imageLoader.get(current.getImageUrl(),
                                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                        holder1.imageView1,
                                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                                )
                        );
                        imageLoader2.get(current.getImageUrl2(),
                                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                        holder1.imageView2,
                                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                                )
                        );
                        imageLoader3.get(current.getImageUrl3(),
                                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                        holder1.imageView3,
                                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                                )
                        );
                        imageLoader4.get(current.getImageUrl4(),
                                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                        holder1.imageView4,
                                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                                )
                        );
                        imageLoader5.get(current.getImageUrl5(),
                                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                        holder1.imageView5,
                                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                                )
                        );


                        holder1.imageView1.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
                        holder1.imageView2.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl2(), imageLoader2);
                        holder1.imageView3.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl3(), imageLoader3);
                        holder1.imageView4.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl4(), imageLoader4);
                        holder1.imageView5.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl5(), imageLoader5);
                        holder1.NameTextView.setText(current.getName());
                        holder1.PhoneNumberTextView.setText(current.getPhone_number());
                        holder1.SubjectTextView.setText(current.getSubject2());



                    } else{
                        final GetDataAdapter current = getItem(position);
                        final ViewHolder holder1 = (ViewHolder) holder;
                        final ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
                        final ImageLoader imageLoader2 = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
                        final ImageLoader imageLoader3 = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
                        final ImageLoader imageLoader4 = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
                        final ImageLoader imageLoader5 = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

                        imageLoader.get(current.getImageUrl(),
                                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                        holder1.imageView1,
                                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                                )
                        );
                        imageLoader2.get(current.getImageUrl2(),
                                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                        holder1.imageView2,
                                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                                )
                        );
                        imageLoader3.get(current.getImageUrl3(),
                                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                        holder1.imageView3,
                                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                                )
                        );
                        imageLoader4.get(current.getImageUrl4(),
                                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                        holder1.imageView4,
                                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                                )
                        );
                        imageLoader5.get(current.getImageUrl5(),
                                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                        holder1.imageView5,
                                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                                )
                        );


                        holder1.imageView1.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
                        holder1.imageView2.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl2(), imageLoader2);
                        holder1.imageView3.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl3(), imageLoader3);
                        holder1.imageView4.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl4(), imageLoader4);
                        holder1.imageView5.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl5(), imageLoader5);
                        holder1.NameTextView.setText(current.getName());
                        holder1.PhoneNumberTextView.setText(current.getPhone_number());
                        holder1.SubjectTextView.setText(current.getSubject2());


                    }
                }
                if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
                    final GetDataAdapter current = getItem(position);
                    final HeaderViewHolder holder1 = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;

                    //set text of header textviews;



                }

            }



            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    return TYPE_HEADER;
                }
                    return TYPE_ITEM;

        }


            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
               if (!getDataAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                   return getDataAdapter.size() + 1;
               } else

                   return getDataAdapter.size();

            }
            private class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                TextView //some Textviews for Header;
                ImageView exerciseimage;

                public HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
                    super(view);


                  // declaring textviews;



                }
            }




        }
```

With

```
@Override
        public int getItemCount() {
           if (!getDataAdapter.isEmpty()) {
               return getDataAdapter.size() + 1;
           } else

               return getDataAdapter.size();

        }
```

I tried to change the size of `getDataAdapter` if it's empty for showing only the Header, but it doesn't work.

Also with

```
else{
                    final GetDataAdapter current = getItem(position);
                    final ViewHolder holder1 = (ViewHolder) holder;
                    final ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
                    final ImageLoader imageLoader2 = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
                    final ImageLoader imageLoader3 = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
                    final ImageLoader imageLoader4 = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
                    final ImageLoader imageLoader5 = ImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

                    imageLoader.get(current.getImageUrl(),
                            ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                    holder1.imageView1,
                                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                            )
                    );
                    imageLoader2.get(current.getImageUrl2(),
                            ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                    holder1.imageView2,
                                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                            )
                    );
                    imageLoader3.get(current.getImageUrl3(),
                            ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                    holder1.imageView3,
                                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                            )
                    );
                    imageLoader4.get(current.getImageUrl4(),
                            ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                    holder1.imageView4,
                                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                            )
                    );
                    imageLoader5.get(current.getImageUrl5(),
                            ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                                    holder1.imageView5,
                                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher_image,
                                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                            )
                    );


                    holder1.imageView1.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
                    holder1.imageView2.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl2(), imageLoader2);
                    holder1.imageView3.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl3(), imageLoader3);
                    holder1.imageView4.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl4(), imageLoader4);
                    holder1.imageView5.setImageUrl(current.getImageUrl5(), imageLoader5);
                    holder1.NameTextView.setText(current.getName());
                    holder1.PhoneNumberTextView.setText(current.getPhone_number());
                    holder1.SubjectTextView.setText(current.getSubject2());


                }
            }
```

I tried to change the `position` in `final GetDataAdapter current = getItem(position);`
 
 I think it's necessary to do something like this `position - 1` or like: `size + 1`, because an `Array` starts counting at `0` and `size` at `1`.

Maybe you can give me a hint or solve my problem.

Comment: What about placing a single "No data found" item just to let the Header show? Maybe that ViewHolder could have "setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)" to make it invisible

Comment: @emandt I can you give me an example? I don't really know what you mean. How can I replace the Header in the "No Data found"?

Comment: I'm on the mobile version of this website and cannot write so much Code from here, so I'll explain better: when your JSON is empty you not create an empty Array Adapter but you will create one single "fake" item just to let the Header became visible. This "fake" item could be "hidden" when the Adapter will place it in the View.

Comment: @emandt Thank you :) Thats a great idea !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was, that I forgot to set the adapter, if the response is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your list, `getDataAdapter`, is empty. Then `getDataAdapter.size() == 0` and `getItemCount()` also returns `0`. Since you always want the header to show, `getItemCount()` should always return at least `1`. I would rewrite it as simply:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return getDataAdapter.size() + 1;
}
```

With that change, there is always a zeroth item in the RecyclerView list. When `getItemViewType()` is called, it will correctly return `TYPE_HEADER` for that zeroth item, and so the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` of the zeroth item will be a `HeaderViewHolder`. (I know that you said something about changing the size of `getDataAdapter` when it's empty, but that seems like a roundabout way of accomplishing the goal here. Your data model shouldn't need to change to accommodate your view.)

Regarding `onBindViewHolder()`: You don't need that nested if-else statement. Since the header is always at the top of the RecyclerView list, the `position` parameter will be `1` when the RecyclerView binds to the first "normal" list item. But the first normal item corresponds to the zeroth item in `getDataAdapter`, so subtract `1`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof ViewHolder) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
        final GetDataAdapter current = getItem(position - 1);
        //bind to normal views
    } else if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
        final HeaderViewHolder headerViewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
        //set text of header textviews
    }
}
```